# Using java.util.Properties to read accented strings from properties file

Tags: java, character-encoding, properties-file, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to read properties from a `constants.properties` file using `java.utils.Properties`. Only, some of these properties contain accented characters like é, è, ô, and when I read them using `getProperty()`, the accents are removed.
ie:

`Générateur de formulaire`

becomes

`Generateur de formulaire`

I know that Property files are read with the ISO 8859-1 encoding, so I've already tried switching out the characters for unicode escapes:

`FORM_GENERATOR_VALUE=Générateur de formulaires`

became

`FORM_GENERATOR_VALUE=G\u0065n\u0065rateur de formulaires`

However this still gives off the same result. When I halt execution and look at the variables, the strings I read from my file with `getProperty()` still have no accents.

Here is how my Properties are initialized:

```
public Properties constants = new Properties();
constants.load(new FileInputStream("constants.properties"));
```

I've seen that one solution would be to switch the Property file format from `.property` to `.xml` but ideally I would like not to have to do that since it would imply rewriting my entire constant file again.

Comment: If you can determine with certainty what encoding your constants.properties file is using, you can specify an explicit encoding with a new [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.InputStream,java.nio.charset.Charset%29), and you can pass that InputStreamReader to [load(Reader)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had accent issue while using french characters so i used the below snippet. We need to pass the charset while reading the .properties file.

```
this.properties.load(new InputStreamReader( getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("configuration.properties"), 
                        Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: It is much better to use proper unicode escapes than specifying non standard encoding. You never know if a tool can change the encoding (IDE, version control...)

Answer (score 1):

`\u0065` is `e`, not `é` (which is `\u00E9`).

So once you set the correct unicode escape, it will be read properly.